# Oracle sqlloader, is possible to insert result in one column only?

Tags: oracle, sql-loader

I have created a column with 0 rows(is new).

```
 alter table CASH add MONEY number(1);
```

I have created a file with values

```
1500$
1600$
1500$
1590$
```

and a "loader.txt" for sqlloader

```
LOAD DATA
INFILE '/var/oracle/file.csv'
INTO TABLE CASH
APPEND
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
TRAILING NULLCOLS
(MONEY)
```

I give the sqlloader command

```
sqlldr myuser/mypass@oracle2/mydb  control=loader.txt log=log.txt ERRORS=10000
```

And give errors

```
Record 4: Rejected - Error on table CASH.
ORA-01400: impossible insert NULL in ("MYUSER"."CASH"."CASH")
```

Why?

Comment: You need an UPDATE instead of INSERT.

Comment: Give me error "SQL*Loader-350: Syntax error at line 4.
Expecting "(", found "UPDATE"."

Comment: And as I know sqlloader cannot update, only insert

Comment: What you do, doesn't make much sense. Table contains a NOT NULL column (CASH), but you'd want to load rows into the newly added column (MONEY). What about CASH column? Can you set it to be NOT NULL? Furthermore, are there any rows in the table? If so, how will you know which row to update by which MONEY value (from the file.csv)? Also, how do you plan to put "1500$" into a NUMBER(1) column?